Dependence of Collision frequency on Temperature
If the formula of collision frequency (as given in Atkins) is 
then it should decrease with increasing temperature if we keep the pressure same. But logically, high temperature means more speed, more collisions and hence more collision frequency. I have searched various online forums but could not understand this

You may have forgotten to consider thermal expansion. At constant volume, the collision rate would increase.

If you keep the volume constant  the rate increases as you expect because $\displaystyle z=\frac{N}{V}\sigma\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{8kT}{\pi\mu}}$

Ohk I missed the expansion, Thankyou guys

Here are the possible loopholes leading to this illogical conclusion.
First, as you fixed the pressure, and found that the formula suggests $$Z_{11} \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}$$ You neglect an other parameter, namely $n$, the number of moles. Known that the collision frequency $$Z_{11} \propto \frac{n^2}{V^2} \cdot \sigma$$ An increase in the temperature increases the number of gas molecules per unit volume by a squared factor (given that the volume does not change). The key point here is that the mean free path is being altered due to some factors that were not accounted for. (Note that $\lambda \propto \frac{1}{N^*}$, which denotes a rise in the collision frequency that can also be explained in the formula later mentioned)
And if you do take the number of moles and volume to be fixed, you still do not account for the factor $\sigma$. We define $$Z_{11} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \pi \sigma^2 v_{av} \times (N^*)^2$$
The above formula strengthens your claim too as $V \propto T$, (known that $N^* = \frac{n}{V}$) but remember that even a slight change in the collision diameter can cause very high variation in the collision frequency. The $\sigma$ is often a neglected factor. Though there is no exact formula that represents the variation of $\sigma$ with temperature, it is a common logic and experimental conclusion that $\sigma \propto \frac{1}{T}$.
Main summary

You do not account for the volume density $N^*$ that alters the mean free path ($\lambda$) and thus the collision frequency by a factor larger than temperature change.
If you take the number of moles and the volume as constant too, you do not account for the collision diameter $\sigma$ that changes with temperature (no exact formula for the change, but $\sigma \propto \frac{1}{T}$, and also that it changes by a squared factor in the formula for collision frequency).

In both the above cases, the factor of square in both $N^*$ and $\sigma$ outcomes the temperature factor, and the collision frequency $Z_{11}$ overall increases.
Moreover, the collision frequency is based upon the average impact angle $\theta$ assumed to be $\frac{\pi}{4}$, that shall too show a deviation with temperature.
Note that most of the formulae of ideal gases (though work in most situations) are not an exact representation of the behavior of a gas as it would show in real scenario.
However, we could still uphold the claim using the formulae only, there could be several other deviations that the formula could not account for...

I think you should review your answer carefully. It maybe bit confusing. Maybe because you are thinking faster than you are able to express your thoughts. For example, you introduce the parameter "n", is this N in the ideal gas expression $pV = NRT$?

By the way, read carefully the comments made to the question.

I appoligize for the inconsistency in the provided answer. The parameter n is indeed supposed to be the number of moles from the ideal gas equation, and have made the changes in the answer as well. Thanks...
